# return an index range of elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

How can I return a range of elements in array like so, without using a For Loop, ForEach Statement, etc.

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]
console.log(array[0-3]);
//result
//1
//2
//3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]

let indexRange = (arr, start, end) => {
  return arr.slice(start, end)
}
console.log(indexRange(array, 0, 3));
```

If your range is string then you can use split and slice

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]

let indexRange = (arr, range) => {
  let [start,end] = range.split('-').map(Number)
  return arr.slice(start, end)
}
console.log(indexRange(array, "0-3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

use slice() method. slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object.

**SYNTAX:**

```
array.slice(start, end)
```

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]
console.log(array.slice(0,3));
//result
//1
//2
//3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function & then pass the range as a string. Inside the function body split the range by the delimiter `-`. Then join the elements of the array and create a string. Use `substr` to get the element between the range. This will create a new string & while returning again split it to create an array

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

function getElemInRange(range) {
  let getRange = range.split('-');
  return array.join('')
    .substr(parseInt(getRange[0], 10), parseInt(getRange[1], 10))
    .split('');
}

console.log(getElemInRange('0-3'));
```